# Building a Bridge

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Your task is to build a bridge to connect two cliffs given an input `d`, the distance apart. `d` will always be even

However, the bridge needs columns to hold it up. Each column can hold a max of 6 spaces on each side.

For this example:

```
________                        ________
        |                      |
   A    |                      |   B

        |----------------------|
                d = 22
```

The bridge for `d = 20`should look like this with two columns. Columns do not count in d.

```
_____|__________|_____
12345|1234554321|12345
     |          |
```

**Rules:**

1. Must have enough columns to stand up.
2. Must have minimum number of columns needed to stand up.
3. Must be symmetrical
4. Lowest amount of Bytes Wins

Examples: (#s are only to help you count spaces. Should not be included in your output)

d = 10

```
_____|_____
12345|12345
     |
```

d = 32

```
_____|___________|___________|_____
12345|12345654321|           |
     |           |           |
```

d = 8

```
____|____
1234|1234
    |
```

d = 4

```
__|__
12|34
  |
```

d = 22

```
_____|____________|_____
12345|123456654321|
     |            |
```

or

```
______|__________|______
123456|1234554321|123456
      |          |
```

Comment: To clarify, are the numbers in the output required, or merely illustrative?

Comment: @isaacg No they are not needed in the output. They are just there so you guys dont have to count lines on my examples.

Comment: I think your specification is flawed? What prevents a 1|2|3|4|5...|d solution where | is a beam.

Comment: @Vlo One of the rules is to use the minimum number of columns possible. Therefore using a column every space would not be the minimum.

Comment: You say d is always going to be even, but in your last example, d=21.

Comment: @Hohmannfan Yes thank you. I fixed it to be 22.

Comment: Why does d=4 require any column at all?

Comment: @KennyLau You need it since the land in this example does not hold the bridge up.... Only columns

Comment: "*Each column can hold a max of 5 or 6 spaces on each side*": which is it: 5 or 6? "*and must have beams going down on each side*": I'm not sure what this means. "*For this example:*" what? Did some text go missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

```
d=>[..."_  "].map(c=>(s=c+c[r='repeat'](n%6))+'|'+(c[r](12)+'|')[r](n/6)+s,n=d-1>>1).join`\n`
```

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character. If `d` can be odd, it takes me 128 bytes:

```
d=>[..."_  "].map(c=>[...Array(d+1)].map((_,i)=>(d&1?i&&d-i&&(i>m)+5+i-m:((d-1)%24>11)*6+i-m)%12?'':'|',m=d>>1).join(c)).join`\n`
```

Comment: How can your solution for odd numbers work? For d=35, none of the optimal solutions are symetrical.

Comment: @Hohmannfan It returns the least suboptimal symmetrical solution, which in this case is `|____________|___________|____________|` etc.

Comment: I guess that is the best interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 108 bytes

Probably can be golfed down a lot more. Greedy algorithm.

```
->d{s='',k=6
(s+=?_*[d,k].min+(d>k/2??|:'');d-=k;k=12)while d>0
s=s.chomp(?|)+s.reverse+$/
s+s.tr(?_,' ')*2}
```